# Enable special characters in form input

Tags: javascript, forms, input, character, entities

I'm looking for a (`preferrably HTML or Javascript`) way to enable my users to place their cursor into any one of my many text input-fields, and type `"CTRL-SHIFT-A,"` and have it display a macron-A entity (`"Ā", also coded as &#256;`). I've already figured out a Javascript way to recognize when `"CTRL-SHIFT-A"` is pressed, but I just don't know how to display "Ā".

---

**Javascript**

```
    <script>

       window.addEventListener("keydown", keysPressed, false);
       window.addEventListener("keyup", keysReleased, false);

       var keys = [];

       function keysPressed(e) {
             keys[e.keyCode] = true;
             if (keys[17] && keys[16] && keys[65]) {

           /*The solution should probably go here.*/

             e.preventDefault(); 
          }
        }

    function keysReleased(e) {
        keys[e.keyCode] = false;
    };

    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<input style="width: 55px;" onkeyup="lettersOnly(this);"></input>
```

Charset is "windows-1252" and it's encoded as "UTF-8 with BOM."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.fromCharCode()` once you find the code of your special character. I looked up your character and [found details on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%80), and in there I used the Unicode value, which is 256. So here an example:

```
alert(String.fromCharCode(256))
```

To go on the "how to place the string into the input control that has focus" you could modify the function as follows:

```
function keysPressed(e) {
         keys[e.keyCode] = true;
         if (keys[17] && keys[16] && keys[65]) {
           // e.target.value is the read/write property of the
           // input field that received the keyboard sequence
           e.target.value=String.fromCharCode(256);
           e.preventDefault(); 
         }
}
```

See it in action at: https://jsfiddle.net/kn3ko9oy/

Comment: Thanks, but alert just displays "Ā" in a pop-up alert window.  However, I need it to display "Ā"  in the cursor's active text-input field.

Comment: I thought the crucial point was how to display "Ā". If you need additional actions, then can you post bits of the html so that we can take a look and test the results? JSFiddle might be a good place for these sort of things.

Comment: BTW, what I wanted to do was slightly different:  Instead of your line of code, which only puts the desired character at the beginning of the string:  `e.target.value=String.fromCharCode(256);` here are 2 lines which will put it anywhere:       `var entry = e.target.value;`
        `e.target.value = entry.concat(String.fromCharCode(256));`

Comment: @rudminda That's awesome. I think the whole idea of SO is to get everyone going past their blocks, and use it for more. Great job, glad I was of help. :) I would also look into jQuery for that would make some of these manipulations much easier.